# How to use toString in R

Tags: r

When I am running the following lines, there is an error saying `Error in toSrting(m) : could not find function "toSrting"`. I have no idea what happened since `toString` usually works well but not here:

```
m <- 1
for(m in 1:60000){
  toSrting(m)
  paste("trainxr", m) <- raster(trainxr[m,,])
  strtoi(m)
  m <- m + 1
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you mean `toString` ?

Comment: Typo,  you have `toSrting` instead of `toString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used R but I think string is spelled wrong.